# Identifying a DateTime formatting convention

Tags: datetime, string-formatting, reverse-engineering, identification

I'm working on a program (we'll call this the `PostProcessor`) that applies some post-processing to the output of another, closed-source program (we'll call this the `Original` program.  Part of the post-processing involves re-calculating a DateTime value and outputting it in the same format as the original.

For example, the `Original` may output:

```
03 : 15 : 30 [h:min:s]
```

The `PostProcessor` calculates that the actual time should be 4 hours, 20 minutes and 10 seconds and should output:

```
04 : 20 : 10 [h:min:s]
```

The "nice" thing is, despite being mostly a black-box, `Original` program has some configuration settings.  Buried deep within these settings is a string value `TimeOutputFormat`, which `PostProcessor` can read.

In the above examples, the `TimeOutputFormat` string was:

```
%#H : %M : %S [h:min:s]
```

Another valid format string I've encountered is:

```
%q2 min
```

Which outputs the total minutes to 2 decimal places.

---

From fiddling around, I've also found the `%c` format string, which outputs in the form:

```
1/1/1970 03:15:30 AM
```

which confirms that the `Original` program is storing these DateTime values in some form of Unix time object.

What I would like to find out is what formatting system is being used, so I can implement it in my `PostProcessor`.  I'm hoping it's a somewhat standard format since I don't have any documentation.  The black-box `Original` program uses a mixture of Visual C++, .NET, and Python modules (and possibly other technologies I'm not aware of).

Here's a catalog of what I've found so far.

- <strike>`#` before the letter (i.e. `%#d`) pads the value with leading 0's</strike>
- `#` removes padding from a value `%d -> 01 but %#d -> 1`
- a digit after the letter (i.e. `%d3') displays decimal digits (if the value has them)

Known formatting strings (from trial/error)

```
%H - Hour component (not total hours, just the hour component)
%M - Minute component
%S - Second component
%a - Day of week (three letter abbrev.)
%b - Month (three letter abbrev.)
%c - Full date (m/d/yyyy HH:MM AM/PM)
%d - Not sure (outputs "01") (guessing day?)
%e-i Not defined
%j - Not sure (outputs "001") (guessing day out of 365?)
%k-l Not defined
%m - Not sure (outputs "01") (guessing month?)
%q - Total minutes
%p - AM/PM
```

If anyone can identify this formatting system, I'd greatly appreciate it.  I'm going to continue to catalog it for my own use, but it would be nice to have some original documentation if it happens to be a publicly available (and hopefully well-documented) system.

Comment: Appears similar to `strftime` in C or Python, but you describe some interesting differences.  Questions:  1) Are you working with elapsed time or time of day?  For example, would 25:00:00 be valid input?  2) What do you mean by "outputs total minutes" for `%q2 min`.  Do you mean it treats it as elapsed time and returns `hours*60 + minutes + seconds/60` ?

Comment: Also, are you sure that `%#d` *pads* a leading zero?  Or could it be that it *removes* it?  In other words, is `%d` "02" and `%#d` is just "2"?

Comment: @MattJohnson 1) "Valid Input" is difficult to define. The `Original` program processes some data and outputs a results file containing among other things a string representation of a time span. The `PostProcessor` processes the same data and overwrites the output file with its calculated time span.  In that regard, "25:00:00" may occur internally in the `Original` program. Based on tinkering with the format strings, I can infer that the internal representation is a date, but the _usage_ is that of a time span

Comment: @MattJohnson The `%q2` behaves as you described (`hours*60 + minutes + seconds/60`).  With regard to `%#d`, I've only tested the `#` behavior on `%#H` and was extrapolating from there, on second look, `%#H` pads with 0's while `%#d` removes 0's.

Comment: That's odd that they would be different behavior.  I was thinking perhaps it used [Microsoft's `strftime` formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak.aspx) - but that would rule that out.  And `%q` is not there either.  Hmmm...

Comment: @MattJohnson you seem to be right about the `#` behavior, I edited the question accordingly. That `%q` is what's getting me as well, since that was in one of the only two format strings I've actually seen "in-the-wild".  It does seem to line up with `strftime` otherwise though.